# Speed up Mysql through indexing

Tags: mysql

I have always queried a table with 7 million rows and hundreds of columns and return results within 20 seconds in MySQL through the following query

```
  SELECT  r.wgt, r.yyyymm, s.fpeDate, s.fileDate, s.stockID, s.endDate, s.Var1, s.Var2, s.Var3
    FROM tableA AS r
    INNER JOIN tableB AS s ON  s.fpeDate >= 201212 AND s.fpeDate <= 201412 AND s.fileDate <20141201 AND s.stockID = r.stockID AND r.yyyymm = 201412;
```

However, when I apppend 1 million rows to the table, using the same query, i get the results around 60 seconds. I have another 20 Millions rows to append to it.

I have created index for tableB for 3 columns fpeDate, fileDate, stockID to make them unique so that any overlapping data are ignored during appending.

```
ALTER TABLE tableA 
    ADD CONSTRAINT uniqueKeys unique INDEX (yyyymm, stockID);

ALTER TABLE tableB
    ADD CONSTRAINT uniqueKeys unique INDEX (fpeDate, fileDate, stockID);
```

When I used EXPLAIN, it is scanning all the rows. Do you have any ideas how I can make it faster?

I used EXPLAIN

```
ID select_type table partitions type possible    keys       key   ref               rows    filtered  ext
1   SIMPLE      s     null      ALL  uniqueKeys  null       null  null              7132508  17.21  Using where
1   SIMPLE      r     null      ref  uniqueKeys  uniqueKeys 38    const,r.stockid   1        100.00
```

1. I have replaced "inner join" with "straight_join". It is worse. Mysql has optimized the query.
2. There are nulls in the columns. I cant put a value to it because nulls means missing values which implied the company at that time do not provide the corresponding values.
3. I have tired to create a index for all the "selected variables" from tableB and run the query. It is very fast.

create index my_id1 on tableB (fpeDate, fileDate, stockID, endDate, Var1, Var2, Var3);

If I create a index as shown below, the query time becomes very long.

```
create index my_id1 on tableB (fpeDate, fileDate, stockID);
```

Now the problem:

1. I cant index all the columns in tableB which have hundreds of columns.
2. The columns I needed will always be different. Example, earlier case, I need Var1, Var2 and Var3. In another case, I may need to load Var5, Var8 and Var10.

Thank you for your advices
L

Comment: It's not clear what you are doing. However - adding more/bigger indexes may be the problem not the solution. Indexes should fit into memory.

Comment: You need to be way more specific.

Comment: I have deleted my answer. You are not forthcoming with information about the query you are trying to optimize, or the table structure. I have lost interest in helping you with this problem.

Comment: I have described what the problem is. I dont think I need to list out all the variable names. It only adds complexity and not simplifying the problem

Answer (score 0):

It requires two ways
1) index in the order of your query

2) Need to index all the selected variables